# Overwrite previous element

Tags: css

Hello there:) I am trying to do something but I don't actually know if it's possible to be done this way. By default there is bottom border on all elements and I want to know if it's possible to overwrite the default bottom border when you hover an element. So in the example, only the blue border should be on and the red one should disappear.

Here is the code example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vnemilov/0a7duc7h/

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
}
ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #5</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should target `<li>` instead of `<a>`.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
}
ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #5</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sidebar Item #6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the border of links (a) not list elements ! 
You've to do it like so :

```
ul li:hover{
border-bottom:3px solid blue;
padding-bottom:6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/0a7duc7h/2/

```
ul li:hover {
    border-bottom:3px solid blue;
    padding:5px 5px 3px 5px; /* changed this because element were moving on hover */
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
}
ul li {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 5px 5px 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="sidebar">
    <li> <a href="#">Sidebar Item #1</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Sidebar Item #2</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Sidebar Item #3</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Sidebar Item #4</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Sidebar Item #5</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Sidebar Item #6</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```